# how to access paratmeter passed in request

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

how to access this paramvalue in controller..?

```
$router->map('Company', 'Company', array( 
 'controller' => 'companies', 
 'action' => 'add', 
 'paramkey' => 'paramvalue', 
 'anotherparam' => 'anothervalue'));
```

Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('paramkey');
```

Comment: can u please help me with the defination of method?

Answer (score 0):

get one param:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('paramkey'[, 'default value']);
```

get all params:

```
$this->getRequest()->getAllParams();
```

or

```
$this->_getParam('paramkey'[, 'default value']);
$this->_getAllParams();
```

I`m using Zend Framework so method described in Zend_Action_Contoller:

```
/**
 * Gets a parameter from the {@link $_request Request object}.  If the
 * parameter does not exist, NULL will be returned.
 *
 * If the parameter does not exist and $default is set, then
 * $default will be returned instead of NULL.
 *
 * @param string $paramName
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function _getParam($paramName, $default = null)
```

if you are using CacePHP you can try

```
$this->params['paramkey'];
```

but I`m not sure it will work

Comment: I have just tested and everything working just fine for me maybe you using wrong or not in controller?

Comment: do u have zend installed?? i mean i guess it should be defined in zend. but the s/w in which i've to do the customization has its own framework but its similar to cakephp...so let me knw where shall i find getParam???

Comment: I`m using Zend Framework so method described in Zend_Action_Contoller:
    /**
     * Gets a parameter from the {@link $_request Request object}.  If the
     * parameter does not exist, NULL will be returned.
     *
     * If the parameter does not exist and $default is set, then
     * $default will be returned instead of NULL.
     *
     * @param string $paramName
     * @param mixed $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function _getParam($paramName, $default = null)
if you are using phpCake you can try

Comment: though my framework is not cakephp...i tried $this->param[] and its not showing error.but not comparing the value though.

Comment: $flag = $this->params['is_owner']; if(flag=='1')

Comment: In mapping i've kept this...                                 $router->map('Owner', 'Owner/true','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'index','is_owner'=> '1'));
    $router->map('Client', 'Client/false','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'index','is_owner'=>'')); 
and in controller.....                                          $flag = $this->params['is_owner'];                                 if(flag=='1'){action;}else{action}                                                          Please help me...m stuck here since 20 days

Comment: maybe sessions for you is better solution :D or you can try just $_GET['is_owner'] and hope it works. I don't know your framework but you should get this param like other GET or POST parameters if you know how.

Comment: what does defaults mean?? i mean ... $router->map('Owner', 'Owner/true','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'index','is_owner'=> '1')); in this the array is stored in defaults..does it pass it with get, post??

Comment: yes it should do that. but you can test that in your framework whatever it is :) good luck

Comment: hey..i did it with $GET...thnx...I want to know how to pass parameter from controller to view.? i m passing flag in defaults.and than accordingly m gettin t in controller i want to check the same flag in view..what shall i do?